# Linq, get distinct elements grouped by a field

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

I feel stupid, but I have to admit, I need your help guys in seemingly easy to find the right answer situation

```
 public class Foo
 {
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public string Time { get; set; }

     public Foo(string name, string time)
     {
        Name = name;
        Time = time;
     }
 }

var o = new List<Foo>
                  {
                      new Foo("Breakfast","9:00"),
                      new Foo("Lunch", "12:00"),
                      new Foo("Breakfast", "8:00")
                  };
```

How to get only Breakfast at 9:00 and Lunch, and not include Breakfast at 8?

I started like that:

```
var a = o.GroupBy(x => x.Name);
```

But it will give you only Name, where I need Time too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var a = o.GroupBy(x => x.Name).Select(g => g.First())
```

But think about that .First() call. How do you want to select the correct element when there is more than one - you might want to sort the elements to get the latest / earliest, or whatever your requirement is.

Comment: Good point about considering what is "correct". Not sure about the latest version, but LINQ-to-EF 4.0 won't actually let you use `First()` without an `OrderBy()`, which makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 3):

One option is:

```
var a = o.GroupBy(x => x.Name)
         .Select(g => g.First());
```

Or you could use [`DistinctBy`](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/trunk/MoreLinq/DistinctBy.cs) from [MoreLINQ](http://morelinq.googlecode.com):

```
var a = o.DistinctBy(x => x.Name);
```

The latter is more efficient in memory, and will start yielding results immediately, whereas the first approach has to read *all* the data before it can return anything. On the other hand, the latter requires MoreLINQ (or copying the code).

EDIT: Here I'm *assuming* LINQ to Objects (as MoreLINQ certainly won't work with other providers) and that you're happy with the first occurrence for any group being representative of that group.

Answer (score 0):

Why not something like the following? (I also took the liberty of making your code a bit smaller -- I think since your properties are public, you don't need a constructor, but can just use object-initializer syntax instead. This should all run in LinqPad:

```
void Main() {
    var os = new [] {
        new Foo{Name="Breakfast",Time="9:00"},
        new Foo{Name="Lunch", Time="12:00"},
        new Foo{Name="Breakfast", Time="8:00"}
    };

    os.Where(o => DateTime.Parse(o.Time).Hour > 8).Dump();
}

public class Foo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Time { get; set; }
}
```